# Searchkick without stemming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am indexing some of my data with searchkick (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) as an array and it works almost fine :)

```
def search_data
  {isbn: isbn, 
   title: title, 
   abstract_long: abstract_long,
   authors: authors.map(&:name)}
end
```

The field I'm interested in is **authors**.
What I'd like to accomplish is to search for "Marias" and find all the authors that actually have that exact string in their surname like (Javier Marias) and not all the Maria/Mario/Marais that Searchkick returns, and have them with a much bigger priority.

This is how I search right now

```
Book.search(@search_key,
            fields: [:authors, :title, {isbn: :exact}],
            boost_by: {authors: 10, title: 5, isbn: 1})
```

Is this possible at all? TIA

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch it has a regular match to deal with this case, but abandoned by Searchkick.
You could choose a walk around way for this case:

```
def search_data
  {
    isbn: isbn, 
    title: title, 
    abstract_long: abstract_long,
    author_ids: authors.map(&:id)
  }
end
```

For search:

```
author_ids = Author.where(surname: 'Marias').map(&:id)
Book.search(
  @search_key,
  where: {author_ids: {in: author_ids}},
  fields: [:title, {isbn: :exact}],
  boost_by: {title: 5, isbn: 1}
)
```